# pagina no encontrada django 2.0.2 python 3.5

Tags: django, django-urls

Solicito de su sapiencia y sabiduria para determinar la razón de que reciba el famoso error 404 cuando intento cargar mi piloto web en Django, la diferencia que tengo en relación a este mismo tema ya explicado varias veces es que yo en el urls.py no indico las páginas con url, sino que ahora django indica que es con path, y al ejecutar el server me indica que todo está correcto, sin embargo al intentar cargar la página recibo ese error.

Agradezco de antemano su atención y apoyo.

Comment: Hola, sería bueno que muestres el código pertinente para tratar de reproducir tu problema y ayudarte. De otra forma es imposible hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias César por atender mi pregunta, pongo abajo el código que estoy usando:  from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Comment: Necesitas actualizar tu pregunta con esa información, ¿a que dirección URL estás accediendo para que te de un 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estas utilizando expresiones regulares en path() que es nuevo en Django 2 como indicabas. esto solo entiende direcciones url escritas de la forma común, ejemplo 'myapp/index/', si deseas que Django entienda las rutas con expresiones regulares debes definirlas con re_path(). En tu caso seria

```
from django.urls import re_path

re_path(r'^$',views.index,name='index')
```

Suponiendo que tienes un proyecto Django donde has creado una app llamada myapp con una vista index, tu urls.py del proyecto general deberia quedar de esta forma:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urs'), /aqui especificas las urls de myapp/*
]
```

y en tu aplicación (en este caso myapp) creas un archivo llamado urls.py también si ya no existe donde pondrás las rutas pertenecientes a esa app en específico que quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),           
    ]
```

si recuerdas en urls.y del proyecto general declaramos `path('myapp/', include('myapp.urs')` esto quiere decir que todo lo que sea myapp/ ve al urls.y de myapp y resuelve, en my app hay una ruta vacía `path('', views.index, name='index'),` que llama a index, por lo que al poner `localhost:8000/myapp` debería salirte la vista index

Comment: Que tal César, muchas gracias por tu colaboración, intenté usar el re_path pero el parser me indicaba error, entonces pasé a usar la forma como lo indicas directamente sin incluir expresiones regulares, quedando de la siguiente manera:\nurlpatterns = [\n
    path('index/',views.index,name='index'),\n sin embargo aún me indicaba que la pagina no existia, tuve que incluir directamente en la dirección el nombre: http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/    Con lo que quedo solucionado el problema, agradezco nuevamente tu apoyo para mi duda, saludos cordiales-